# How do you check for a specific argument number in a count?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a SQLite3 tool and focusing on the input mechanic. I was wondering how you check for a specific argument number in a count to parse the next line of code. Here's an example of the value at question, `-copy -i filename.db -o output.db`. How would I scan for the `-i` and then detect where the system argument is to get the count of one over. The ultimate propose of this being so complicated is so that the arguments can be flexible to the user. I cant require the argument to be in a specific area too. Shown below is my current function that I am trying to apply this too. The comments are the areas of discussion. Thank you for all your help :), i'll make sure to get to everyone.

```
class Processing:

  def processing():
    def __init__(self, arg):
      self.arg = arg;
      args = len(arg)

      #if "-i" in arg:
          # find what argument -i is in
          # check following argument
          # read that following line
          sqlInit.registerInput('filename from argument')

# SQLINIT is a custom class i've made
```

Comment: Take a look at [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: @enzo Thanks for your response. I'm looking into it but I ran into another problem.